# How to show one by one record on the UI returning from the Web API?

Tags: c#, ajax, angular, entity-framework-6

**Just for information:**

I can not use the pagination (skip, take) since the records are coming from the multiple tables. For detail you can check the `Report` model.

I have to tried to get the data `one by one` on the UI from WebAPI.

The below code fetches all the records at a time but the records are huge and it takes more than a minute which is not good as per UX.

**Model**

```
public class Report 
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public List<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
    public List<State> StateList { get; set; }
    public List<District> DistrictList { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetReports()
{
  var tempReports = this.mService.GetReports();
  if (tempReports == null)
  {
    return ErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  }

  return OK(tempReports);
}
```

**Service**

```
public IEnumerable<Report> GetReports() 
{
List<int> totalValidRecords = ; //This comes from a table on the basic of which the report will be generated.

foreach(int id in totalValidRecords)
{
   List<Region> regions= //gets list of record from Region table.

   foreach(Region region in regions)
   {
      List<Country> countries= //gets list of countries from country table based on region.

      foreach(Country country in counties)
      {
        List<State> states = //gets list of states from State table based on country.

        foreach(State state in states)
        {
           List<District> districts = //gets list of districts from District table based on state.

           //Other logic which computes and access other rest of dependent tables data.
        }
      }
   }
  yield return report; 
}
}
```

Comment: You should have logic implemented to retrieve paged data from the database itself. It should expect the pageNumber and PageSize parameter and get the data from database only for that page. The nested foreach loop in your code are not good thing to have. You need to figure out better way to retrieve all data in one query. You need to share more code around how exactly are you fetching data for the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want it's called WebSockets and for .net you have a library SignalR which allows you to create connections to those websockets where you will send data to that channel  when the front end makes that request you connect to the right channel and all the data sent there you can start by showing in your interface, that's a solution that requires some effort to setup but I would highly suggest it to you.
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Example : FrontEnd request API , API gets the first list 'regions' filled send to the channel all the regions, front end will receive those values and populate some variable and display to the user, and so on...